# Excel, round down to nearest .95?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a request to create a cell with a formula that is 50% of another cell, rounded down to the nearest .95 (basically it's a clearance price).

How can I do that in excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=INT(<original val> / 2 + 0.05) - 0.05
```

Do you really want $3.89 to become $0.95? Because that's what rounding down to the nearest 0.95 does.

Also, note that for original prices of less than $1.90, this formula generates a price of $-0.05, which is what you asked for but is silly.

Comment: No, that's rounding to the nearest .95. Rounding *down* to the nearest .95 would be 2.95.

Comment: Yes, the problem I'm having is edge cases like 27.90, which should be 13.95, not 12.95.  The formula I have so far is `=ROUNDDOWN(A3*.5, 0)-0.05`

Comment: @Dennis half of $3.89 is $1.945. Rounding *down* to the nearest 0.95 gives $0.95. You can't round it to $1.95, because that would round *up*.

Comment: @Chad: the formula in my answer works fine for $27.90.

Comment: It's just to populate a worksheet with defaults.  So the negative price shouldn't be an issue.  I used ROUNDDOWN instead of int, as it's more descriptive to the action.  But it's working.  Thanks